# How can disable or delete before new one created specific nuget package cache in $User_Profile$\.nuget\packages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget

I would like to delete existing nuget package in ($User_Profile$.nuget\packages) before package that is created when project is builded by developer in local environment for specific package name. But I can not find any way or solution. How can ı disable?